# SVG drawing created by Inkscape not displayed properly on Lyx

Tags: lyx, svg, inkscape

I created an SVG figure using Inkscape and inserted it into my Lyx paper. But the figure is not properly display either on lyx or the pdf it generated. For example, an arrow "--->" becomes a line "---". Sometimes different parts of my drawing get misplaced when displayed in lyx.

Comment: Install 'rsvg-convert' (on Ubuntu just do `sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin`), then in LyX go to Tools > Reconfigure. Try again. Does that change anything?

Comment: If you are under Linux or OS X it could also be this bug: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9778 If so, there's still a problem with the converter, see @scottkosty's comment.